# Jquery: get the text of the selected option in this

Tags: jquery-selectors

If the input is a select type, I want to get the text of the selected option, not the value.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.encodageField').live('change', function(){
  if( $(this).is('select') ) {
      val = $($(this) + 'option:selected').text();
      alert (val);
  }else{
      val = $(this).val;
      alert (val);
  }
  save_answer($(this));
});
```

So I need the text of $(this) the changed select. How do I use 'this' in combination with 'option:selected' as a selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
val = $('option:selected', this).text();
```

Comment: Unbelievable, this is something so simple and it took me a long time and a question here to find the answer. I don't know how to thank you for the quick and correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be equivalent to Leigh's answer

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Comment: It would, I believe the first option is just slightly more concise

Comment: @LeighCiechanowski I agree. The reason that i brought it up is because jquery will convert your snippet to mine :)